# apparent 'newline character' at the end of my code

Tags: python

I'm being told by the website I use that there is an extra newline character being printed at the end. I don't really know where abouts it is though or what is causing it. I thought it would be where I put `("Name: ")` with the space, but no it's not.

```
listo = []
name = input("Name: ")
listo.append(name)
while name:
  while name:
    name = input("Name: ")
    if name:
      listo.append(name)
listo.sort()
listo.reverse()
for name in listo:
  print(name)
```

Error:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do you get any kind of traceback? Also, what website is this?

Comment: Well it's a website called Grok Learning where I am learning python. And sorry instead of whitespace I meant newline. It says: Your output has an extra trailing newline character.

Comment: `print()` adds a newline

Comment: What is the purpose of the task? You can change the line endings in `print` if it's all supposed to be on one line

Comment: I added an image in post to show example. each name on separate lines

Comment: But I have only done   `print(name)` not `print()` ?

Comment: @HollyM I think the answer by FlyingTeller is the issue. We've been focused on `print` but it's the way you terminate your `while` loop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at

```
while name:
  name = input("Name: ")
  listo.append(name)
```

this while loop terminates when you hit enter on the input line without entering anything else, hence setting `name=""` which would evaluate to `false` in the condition of the while loop. But you are adding that to the list `listo` anyway. THerefor, when you do

```
for name in listo:
  print(name)
```

it prints all the actual names you have entered, plus one additional empty line with a newline at the end(added by print).

To fix this, you can check in the while loop if name is not empty:

```
while name:
  name = input("Name: ")
  if name:
    listo.append(name)
```

But doing only that will have a trailing `\n` when no name is read at all (from the first `listo.append(name)` before the loop). Alternatively, you could change the order of the lines in the while loop and move every append in there:

```
listo = []
name = input("Name: ")
#listo.append(name) move to while loop
while name: 
  listo.append(name) #order changed, while loop runs while there is still a name to add. The empty name will terminate the while loop, hence never reaching the appen line
  name = input("Name: ") 
listo.sort()
listo.reverse()
for name in listo:
  print(name)
```

Comment: @HollyM I think we're going to struggle on this because it's a website task and not really a python issue. I have no idea what it's complaining about with your edit, your code looks good to me